Can i get infected if I open a malware binary file in Python like this? open(file_path, 'rb').read()
I need to calculate the hash and send a file via HTTP of a binary that have malware. To do that I need to use this two functions:
hashlib.md5(open(file_path, 'rb').read()).hexdigest()
file = {'file': (file_path.name, open(file_path, 'rb'))}

I know that it opens the file located at file_path in binary read mode. I am almost sure nothing happens because It is only going to open the file in read mode and read the it in binary mode. But I want to get sure because I didn´t find anything in the internet.

...but how does the malware do anything if you just read the bytes? I think it'd have to be specifically a malware that exploited some vulnerability in Python file reading code?

I believe so. If the malware doesn´t exploit any vulnerability in the library that I am using to open it nothing is going to happen.

Reading a binary malware file will not be a problem. The problem with malware binaries is when they execute in some fashion, reading them as binary is not execution.

@Paul Do you also think that if I email a file to you but you don't open the file or interact with it in anyway, that you're safe?

Reading a malware file as binary is not where the risk lies. It is harmless. The fact that you have a malware file on your computer is the problem. It may execute under some cron job or by any other means that is not obvious, including receiving it via email and then opening it as it was intended to be opened by the author. Reading it as a binary through a python script will not trigger malicious code contained in it. Same as looking at or even dissecting a firearm under proper conditions being super safe. Problem is when it is used as it was intended to be used.

@Paul What if you have an antivirus software that scans every file when it is read, and that file is compressed and the antivirus software unpacker is vulnerable? How is that harmless? What am I missing? See for example this page describing something like that and saying "These vulnerabilities are as bad as it gets".

This question belongs on information security.
